# Android Studio 4.1.2 NDK path config error

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-ndk

when running program in Mac Pro 10.15.7,

Android Studio 4.1.2 reports

> NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.

when handling in File / Project Structure/ SDK Location

[image: 888]

This is the same, neither are its sub folders

[image: 77]

I can not save it , very strange

---

I have tried download the latest

[image: 999]

how to solve the NDK problem?

Comment: Not enough information. What version of the gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Solved. Code error, Android Studio reports sth unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

because of come code error,

Android Studio reports sth unrelated, like this